# React/RCTAssert.h file not found

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

Podfile:

platform :ios, '9.0'

```
require_relative'../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
 
pre_install do |installer|
 installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
if pod.name.eql?('RNScreens') || pod.name.eql?('RNCMaskedView') || pod.name.eql?('RNCSafeAreaShadowView')
defpod.build_type
Pod::BuildType.static_library
end
end
end
end
 
defadd_flipper_pods!(versions = {​​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​​)
 versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.33.1'
 versions['DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
 versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.1'
 versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
 versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
 versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.0'
 
 pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 
# List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
# to avoid them being linked in Release builds
 pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['DoubleConversion'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
 pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
end
 
# Post Install processing for Flipper
defflipper_post_install(installer)
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
if target.name == 'YogaKit'
 target.build_configurations.each do |config|
 config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
end
end
end
 post_install do |installer|
 flipper_post_install(installer)
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
 t.build_configurations.each do |config|
 config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
end
end
end
 
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
 target.build_configurations.each do |config|
 config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
end
end
end
 
target 'MyApp'do
# Pods for MyApp
 pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
 pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
 pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
 pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
 pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
 pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
 pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
 pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
 pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
 pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
 pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
 pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
 pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
 pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
 pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
 pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
 pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
 pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
 
 pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
 pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
 pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
 pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
 pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
 pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
 pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true
 
 pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
 pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
 pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
 
 pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'
 
 target 'MyAppTests'do
 inherit! :complete
# Pods for testing
end
 
 use_native_modules!
 use_frameworks!
# Enables Flipper.
#
# Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
# you should disable these next few lines.
# add_flipper_pods!
 post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
if target.name == 'React'
 target.remove_from_project
end
end
end
end
 
target 'MyApp-tvOS'do
# Pods for MyApp-tvOS
 
 target 'MyApp-tvOSTests'do
 inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      React & ReactNative versions:                                                                                                                                              

"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "^0.62.0",
```

Tried the below solution but it was only a temporary fix: #if __has_include(" RCTAssert.h")

```
  #import " RCTAssert.h" 
#else 
   #import <React/ RCTAssert.h> 
#endif
```

When I use rm -rf node_modules && npm install or cd ios && pod deintegrate && pod install, the same error occurs again.

Added RNCSlider to Manage Schema
React Native Slider version:                                                                                                                                             "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",

Comment: In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:23:

../react-native/React/Base/RCTUtils.h:14:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTAssert.h' file not found

#import <React/RCTAssert.h>

        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.